# wordpress adding plugin for ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

i am new to wordress. trying to test creating a plugin to combine my js and ajax for a module. I did the following:

[Not sure if i need to add anything in admin-ajax.php.]

1. created my new plugin under wp-content/pluging/test-plugin
2. created 2 files: test.php and test.js
3. test.php content as the following:

   /**
        * Plugin Name: Test
        */

   ```
   add_action("wp_ajax_my_test", "my_test");

   add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_my_test", "my_test");

   function my_test()
   {
   echo "in ajax";
   }
   add_action( 'init', 'test_script_enqueuer' );


   function test_script_enqueuer() {

       wp_register_script( "test", WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/my_plugin/test.js', array('jquery') );
       wp_localize_script( 'test', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));

       wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
       wp_enqueue_script( 'test');
   }
   ```
4. test.js code as the following:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function()
           {    
   console.log('in js!');
   ```

   $('#testDiv').on('click', '#test', function()
   {
   console.log('clicked!');

   jQuery.ajax(
                           {
                               type: 'POST',
                               url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
                               data:
                               {
                                   action: 'my_test'
                               },
                               dataType: 'json',
                               cache: false,
                               success: function(response)
                               {
       alert(response);
                               },
                               error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
                               {
                                  alert('error');
                               }
                           });
   })

   ```
       });
   ```

Note that I can't even see the "in js!" message in my console.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
add_action( 'init', 'test_script_enqueuer' );
```

to

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "test_script_enqueuer");
```

But first, try to echoes something from your php file. If nothing happened your file isn't call.

Try then tell me.

Comment: thanks. update my js code. i can see 'in js!' in console. but on click doesn't seem to be triggered, cant see 'clicked!' that i have printed. any idea?

Comment: replace 
$('#testDiv').on('click', '#test', function() { console.log('clicked!');

By
$('#testDiv').on('click', function() { console.log('clicked!');

I remove the '#test' in your event.

Comment: add die(); after echo "in ajax"; in your function my_test()